# XSL recursion, how to match?

Tags: xslt, recursion

I have to make a recursion to add some values and return a total. I have a XML file and for each coloc_id, I need to return a total of what is inside "montant". For example, for my XML below, I need to return :

```
Balthazar : 732
Gaspard : 172 (87+87)
Melchior : 1239 (1236+3) 
Jesus : 104
```

I can't use foreach, this is prohibited in my exercise. I searched for 3 hours but I can't figure out what I need to do. Below there is my xsl file, which display :

```
Balthazar:732.
Gaspard:87.
Gaspard:87.
Melchior:1236.
Melchior:3.
Jesus:104.
```

But I want a total, and I don't know how to match several element with the same coloc_id at the same time.

```html
<comptes>
 <actions>
  <depense coloc_id="Melchior" categorie="loyer" date="2016-12-12">
   <montant>1236
   </montant>
   <pour coloc_id="Melchior"/>
   <pour coloc_id="Balthazar"/>
  </depense>
  <depense coloc_id="Melchior" categorie="loyer" date="2016-12-12">
   <montant>3
   </montant>
   <pour coloc_id="Melchior"/>
   <pour coloc_id="Balthazar"/>
  </depense>
  <depense coloc_id="Balthazar" categorie="meuble">
   <montant>732
   </montant>
   <pour coloc_id="Gaspard"/>
   <pour coloc_id="Balthazar"/>
  </depense>

  <depense coloc_id="Gaspard" categorie="alimentation">
   <montant>87
   </montant>
   <pour coloc_id="Balthazar"/>
   <pour coloc_id="Gaspard"/>
  </depense>

  <depense coloc_id="Gaspard" categorie="alimentation" >
   <montant>87
   </montant>
   <pour coloc_id="Balthazar"/>
   <pour coloc_id="Gaspard"/>
   <pour coloc_id="Melchior"/>
   <pour coloc_id="Jesus"/>
  </depense>

  <depense coloc_id="Jesus" categorie="alimentation" >
   <montant>104
   </montant>
   <pour coloc_id="Balthazar"/>
   <pour coloc_id="Gaspard"/>
   <pour coloc_id="Melchior"/>
   <pour coloc_id="Jesus"/>
  </depense>
 </actions>
 
 <colocataires>
  <coloc id="Melchior">Melchior</coloc>
  <coloc id ="Balthazar">Balthazar</coloc>
  <coloc id="Gaspard">Gaspard</coloc>
 </colocataires>

</comptes>
```

And my xsl file :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//depense[@coloc_id='Balthazar']" mode="ok">
      <xsl:with-param name="personne">Balthazar</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//depense[@coloc_id='Gaspard']" mode="ok">
      <xsl:with-param name="personne">Gaspard</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//depense[@coloc_id='Melchior']" mode="ok">
      <xsl:with-param name="personne">Melchior</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//depense[@coloc_id='Jesus']" mode="ok">
      <xsl:with-param name="personne">Jesus</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="ok">
    <xsl:param name="personne"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$personne"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="DepenseMelchior">
      <xsl:with-param name="coloc"><xsl:value-of select="$personne"/></xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="total">0</xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="index_courant">1</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>.&#xa;</xsl:text>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="DepenseMelchior">
    <xsl:param name="coloc"/>
    <xsl:param name="total"/> 
    <xsl:param name="index_courant"/> 
    <xsl:choose> 
      <xsl:when test="$index_courant = count(*)+ 1"> 

        <xsl:value-of select="$total"/>
      </xsl:when> 
      <xsl:otherwise> 

        <xsl:choose> 
          <xsl:when test="self::node()[@coloc_id=$coloc]"> 
            <xsl:variable name="un_nombre"><xsl:value-of select="montant"/></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:call-template name="DepenseMelchior">
              <xsl:with-param name="total"><xsl:value-of select="$total  + $un_nombre"/></xsl:with-param> 
              <xsl:with-param name="index_courant"><xsl:value-of select="$index_courant + 1"/></xsl:with-param> 
            </xsl:call-template> 
          </xsl:when> 
          <xsl:otherwise> 
            <xsl:call-template name="DepenseMelchior"> 
              <xsl:with-param name="total"><xsl:value-of select="$total"/></xsl:with-param> 
              <xsl:with-param name="index_courant"><xsl:value-of select="$index_courant + 1"/></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template> 
          </xsl:otherwise>   
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: To me it sounds like a grouping problem you can solve in XSLT 2.0 using `xsl:for-each-group` or in XSLT 1.0 using Muenchian grouping http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml, once you have a group you can then `sum(current-group()/montant)` in XSLT 2.0 or the same using the `key` function in XSLT 1.0.  I don't see a need for recursion.

Comment: "Jesus" is missing from the `colocataires` list. Is this intentional?

Comment: It isn't necessary to use `<xsl:call-template>` in order to implement recursion. Typically `<xsl:apply-templates>` implements recursive processing (it is actually very difficult to process a tree (a recursively defined data structure) in a non-recursive way. But it is preferable to use a non-recursive solution (such as a short expression) always when this is possible. There are some run-time issues with recursion (such as stack-overflow) if it is used naively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `key` to group nodes. This example templates the `coloc` elements, using a key to sum the amounts that match by `coloc_id`.

Note that this doesn't print the sum for all `coloc`s, as one of them is missing from the `colocataires` list (*Jesus*).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <!-- Map of depense by coloc_id -->
    <xsl:key name="depense-coloc" match="/comptes/actions/depense" use="@coloc_id"/>

    <!-- Template each coloc in the colocataires list -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/comptes/colocataires/coloc"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template a coloc -->
    <xsl:template match="coloc">
        <!-- Name -->               <!-- Sum of depense/montant for matching coloc_id -->
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>: <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('depense-coloc', @id)/montant)"/>
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could use recursion, but it would be clunkier:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <!-- Template each coloc in the colocataires list -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/comptes/colocataires/coloc"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template a coloc -->
    <xsl:template match="coloc">
        <!-- Name -->               <!-- Template the first depense for matching coloc_id -->
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>: <xsl:apply-templates select="/comptes/actions/depense[@coloc_id=current()/@id][1]"/>
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Sum the montant of a depense and all following depense elements -->
    <xsl:template match="depense">
        <xsl:variable name="next">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::depense[@coloc_id=current()/@coloc_id][1]"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(0, $next) + montant"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the end a straight-forward sum is clearer and more compact:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <!-- Template each coloc in the colocataires list -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/comptes/colocataires/coloc"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template a coloc -->
    <xsl:template match="coloc">
        <!-- Name -->               <!-- Sum of depense/montant for matching coloc_id -->
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>: <xsl:value-of select="sum(/comptes/actions/depense[@coloc_id=current()/@id]/montant)"/>
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you it works very well, indeed I forget Jesus in coloc. So it isn't possible to make my recursion work ? I have to use xsl key to sum the "montant" ?

Comment: I added another two example methods to the answer.